# How to pass an array values from one function to another function in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to get the array values from
"`validateBeforeSubmit`" function to "**saveForm**" function. But I am
getting values of "`undefined`" in "`arrlength`". Please help me to solve.

This my code  in vue.js

```js
export default {
  name: '',
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.validateBeforeSubmit()
    this.saveForm();
  },
  methods: {
    validateBeforeSubmit() {
      var fieldsVal = new Array();
      var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value
      var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value
      var designation = document.getElementById('designation').value

      if (firstName != "" && lastName != "" && designation != "") {
        fieldsVal.push(firstName);
        fieldsVal.push(lastName);
        fieldsVal.push(designation);
        return fieldsVal;
      } else {
        fieldsVal.length = 0;
        return fieldsVal;
      }
      return fieldsVal;
    },

    saveForm() {
      var fieldsValArray = this.validateBeforeSubmit();
      var arrLength = fieldsValArray.length;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see multiple issues in your code:

1) Don't apply jQuery-like approach for getting input values. Use `v-model` instead. This will simplify your code

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="form.firstName" type="text"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: {
    form: { 
      firstName: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validateBeforeSubmit() {
      // take `firstName` directly from `data` not need for `getElementById`
      const firstName = this.form.firstName;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

2) Remove `validateBeforeSubmit` and `saveForm` from `ready`. Ready hook is obsolete in `vue@2`. And also it makes no sense. It's better to call it on form `@submit`.

3) It's better to create array using `[]` syntax instead of `new Array()`

> [Why never use new Array in Javascript](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript)

4) Always provide name for your component for easier debug

```js
export default {
   name: 'ValidationForm',
}
```

5) I don't know where was an issue but it works. Check this link below. I have updated your code. Try to submit form and check the console:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/w6jl619qr5?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FForm.vue

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you have enough time kindly answer for my another question & the question link is: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039160/want-to-know-the-debugging-process-of-vue-js-because-when-compare-to-javascript)